# I want Ascending 1st div text inside li..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-lists

This Is My ul li div Structure

On click checkbox I Want Ascending My 1st `div text` inside `li`

```js
    $(".ascsection").click(function(){                 
        var items = $('#Section li').get();
        items.sort(function(a,b){
            var keyA = $("div:first", a).text();
            var keyB = $(b).text();
            if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
            if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        var ul = $('#Section');
        $.each(items, function(i, li){
            ul.append(li);
        });    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Section">
       <li>
         <span style="display:flex;">
           <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" class="abc bethgfont" style="float:left;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;text-align: left;width: 50%;padding-bottom: 7px;">abc</div>
           <div style="display:none;">27</div>
           <div style="display:none;">Sub Section 1</div>
           <div id="syriacname-27" class="syriacSection" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 10px;text-align: right;width: 50%;padding-bottom: 7px;">Syriac 1</div>
         </span>
       </li>
       <li>
         <span style="display:flex;">
           <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" class="abc bethgfont" style="float:left;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;text-align: left;width: 50%;padding-bottom: 7px;">def</div>
           <div style="display:none;">27</div>
           <div style="display:none;">Sub Section 1</div>
           <div id="syriacname-27" class="syriacSection" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 10px;text-align: right;width: 50%;padding-bottom: 7px;">ashoka</div>
         </span>
       </li>
    </ul>

 

    <input type="checkbox" class="ascsection" value="" />
```

Thanks In Advance

this code is working. but i want ascending only 1st div text in li.

Comment: Perhaps you need to change `$(a).text();` to `$("div:first", a).text();`

Comment: @SalmanA this code is working but i want ascending only 1st div. your code through ascending li but i want ascending only 1st div. thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure what you are asking, but this makes your function work for the divs.

```js
    $(".ascsection").click(function(){                 
        var items = $('#Section li div').get();
        items.sort(function(a,b){
            var keyA = $(a).text();
            var keyB = $(b).text();
            if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
            if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
            return 0;
        });
        var ul = $('#Section');
        $.each(items, function(i, li){
            ul.append(li);
        });    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="Section">
       <li>
         <span style="display:flex;">
           <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" class="abc bethgfont" style="float:left;margin-left: 10px;margin-top: 10px;text-align: left;width: 50%;padding-bottom: 7px;">Section</div>
           <div style="display:none;">27</div>
           <div style="display:none;">Sub Section 1</div>
           <div id="syriacname-27" class="syriacSection" style="float: right;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 10px;text-align: right;width: 50%;padding-bottom: 7px;">Syriac 1</div>
         </span>
       </li>
    </ul>

 

    <input type="checkbox" class="ascsection" value="" />
```

Comment: this Code Is not Working.i want On Click CheckBox Ascending My First div Text. This div Is Inside li

Comment: You arent making sense, the code i put sorts the divs the only divs in your code.